# Usar dos nameservers distintas para un mismo dominio

Tags: dns, dominio, subdominio

les explico mi problema y aclaro que soy nueva en esto de las DNS y los nameservers. Mi cliente tenía muchos dominios para distintas versiones de su página web (por ejemplo por el idioma) pero quiere reducir costos usando un solo dominio con varios subdominios. Hasta ahí todo bien. Pero el problema surge por lo siguiente: su dominio está en neubox y el hosting que usaremos para almacenar la info de los subdominios; pero quiere que el dominio principal apunté a su hosting que se encuentra en wix y que los subdominios apunten al hosting que está en neubox; me gustaría saber si esto es posible y si saben cómo hacerlo me pudieran auxiliar diciéndome cómo. Se los agradezco mucho.

Comment: Tienes que acceder a la cónsola donde se gestiona el DNS y ahí asignar cada dominio (y subdominio) a una IP.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho! Muchas gracias Roger Torné ^^

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, la idea de usar dos o más nameservers distintos (de distintos proveedores) es posible pero extremadamente inusual. Implica configurar [delegación por zona](https://www.cloudns.net/blog/dns-delegation/), que no es trivial ni todos los proveedores lo ofrecen. No se me ocurre un caso de uso genérico que lo necesite.

---

Lo que tú quieres hacer pareciera ser mucho más simple, y lo hubieses comprobado de intentarlo, pero imagino que se produce un Catch-22 donde no puedes ensayar sin certeza de que sea factible. Así que para que quedes tranquila, **no sólo es factible. Es el caso de uso más general.**

Creo que lo único que necesitas saber es que, aunque un proveedor puede ofrecer un "combo" que incluye dominio, DNS y alojamiento, son servicios separados, y sin importar que contrates el combo puedes llevarte el dominio adonde quieras (pero dejando [60 días entre transferencias](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en)) y designar como DNS autoritario el que tú quieras (desde el día 0).

Como te lo puedes llevar donde quieras y cuando quieras, sería contraproducente para un proveedor intentar retenerte a la fuerza. Al revés, todos tienen paneles para que el cliente se autoatienda.